# Multiple Text components with a line break in React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get a paragraph to align properly in React Native but so far I have been unable to reach the desired look for it.

This component is a simple box with three main `<Text/>` components. Each one of these components has a completely different style and they receive a string variable passed down as props.

The final look I'm going for is:

[image: Component look]

I've tried building the component as follows:

```
<View style={layoutStyles.mainContainer}>
      <View style={layoutStyles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={textStyles.highlightedText}>{highlightedText}</Text>
        <View style={layoutStyles.contentContainer}>
          <Text style={textStyles.content}>{content}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Text style={textStyles.linkText}>{link}</Text>
      <View style={layoutStyles.exitContainer}>
        <Icon
          name="CROSS"
          style={textStyles.exitText}
          lineHeight={30}
          size={25}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
```

and styled it as so:

```
    export const layoutStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    marginVertical: 40,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 355,
    height: 74,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },
  textContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    width: 180,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  exitContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
});

export const textStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  highlightedText: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 18,
    fontWeight: '600',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  content: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 18,
  },
  linkText: {
    color: 'grey',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    fontSize: 12,
    lineHeight: 18,
  },
  exitText: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});
```

But as it is made obvious by the colors of the backgrounds, I've no idea how to align the text so the "content" drops down below the "highlighted text"

I'm clueless as to how to solve it. Any help is deeply appreciated.

[image: my broken alignment]

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the text to appear within the red square of your last image. That won't work because then the text would need to be defined inside that `View`. I would restructure so that you have three areas with text. Based on your last image, you could do this:

[image]

and here is how you could implement it

```
<View style={{alignSelf: 'center',marginVertical: 40, width: 355, height: 74, flexDirection: 'column' }} >
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
        <View >
            <Text>{'Highlighted text'}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginLeft: 10}} >
            <Text>{'then some regular'}</Text>
        </View>
        </View>
        <View >
            <Text>{'text which drops a line and goes on here'}</Text>
        </View>
    </View >
```

Edit:
If the reason for wanting a line break is for the string to fit you could divide the string using substring into two different parts of appropriate size. To divide the string without splitting words, you could do something like this:

```
render() {
    const { highlightedText, content } = this.props
    const characterLimit = 20;
    let splitIndex = characterLimit; 
    while(content.charAt(splitIndex) !== ' ' && splitIndex > 0) { 
        splitIndex--;
    }
    const first = content.substring(0, splitIndex);
    const second = content.substring(splitIndex + 1, content.length);
    return (
        <View style={{alignSelf: 'center',marginVertical: 40, width: 355, height: 74, flexDirection: 'column' }} >
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
                <View >
                    <Text>{highlightedText}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{marginLeft: 10}} >
                    <Text>{first}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View >
                <Text>{second}</Text>
            </View>
        </View >
    );
```

Comment: That would work but the component I'm building recieves only three props, "highlighted text", "content", and "link". This cannot be altered so I need the green rectangle to drop below the blue one. I'm beginning to think that it just might not be possible.

Comment: Does the `content` string contain a newline character? If it does, then you can split the string and render the different parts in the different squares. For example 'foo\nbar' would then be split to 'foo' and 'bar'.

Comment: Thin is the component will be reused with loads of different information which is updated automatically via the backend, I've no way of altering the text variables.

Comment: By splitting I don't mean that you should alter the original text variables. Splitting will create a new array of strings. For example 'foo\nbar'.split('\n');` evaluates to `['foo', 'bar']`. You can use this to dynamically render the content prop across different squares. If the reason for wanting a line break is for the string to fit you could divide the string using `substring` into two different parts of appropriate size.

Comment: Hadn't considered that option, but how would I go about splitting the string taking into consideration not breaking any word in half?

Comment: One way you could do it is to define a maximum number of characters allowed in the square, and then finding the largest index smaller than the limit and at which there is a space. Something like: `while(str.charAt(index) !== '  ' && index > 0) index--;`

Comment: could you modify your answer so it shows this approach? I'll accept it if it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have a line breaker function that might help you. just pass the string and maximum characters allowed in each line and it returns a multi-line string.

```
const breakTextByNumber = (chars: string, seperator: number) => [...chars].flatMap((value, i) => (i > 0 && i % seperator == 0) ? '\n' + value : value);
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use Text components like this:

```
<Text style={style1}> 
  {'Highlighted text'}
  <Text style={style2}>
   {'text2'}
  </Text>
</Text>
```